# reference array in for loop generated hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

How can i reference an array item with the same index as the the array used in my for loop?

animations[i] current returns as undefined:

```
var icons = ["#know","#run","#think","#done","#measure","#plan","#resolve"]
var animations = [knowTl,runTl,thinkTl,doneTl,measureTL,planTl,resolveTl]

for(var i=0;i<icons.length;i++) {
$(icons[i]).hover(
  function() {
  animations[i].restart()
  },
  function() {}
 );
}
```

Comment: do you mean animations[i].restart() ??

Comment: sorry, corrected

Comment: ahh okay i see.. you need to create closure in your bindings. like (function(){})()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this

```
for(var i=0;i<icons.length;i++) {
(function(i){
  $(icons[i]).hover(
    function() {
      animations[i].restart()
    },
    function() {}
   );
})(i)
}
```

Comment: This code will work, but theres plenty of ways to do it better.

Comment: Sorry man but Your answer provides no explanation why and how it works. If if suits the author than well... Not my code, not my problem.

Comment: @grzesiekgs _This code will work, but theres plenty of ways to do it better_ you should add these solutions to your anwser?

Comment: i actually explained it to him at the comment section of his question. to create a closure. :)

Comment: @smarber I've explained exactly where he has made a mistake, and I've also provided the shortest answer which I've got in my mind at the time. What else do You need? :)

Comment: @grzesiekgs Your anwser is great but it's ES6 which means it won't work in browsers not supporting ES6 yet.

Comment: @smarber Well we live in era of babel, IE10 is no longer supported, IE11 soon to be.
If You are working with JS and You don't know ES6 yet, than You definitely should start learning it ;)

And all You need to change in my answer, is to replace 'const' with 'var', arrow function with 'normal' function, and destructuring with variables.

Comment: es6 is the future yes it. and that's why babel or other transpiler exist because other browser doesn't support es6 syntax yet. and also the issue of browser compatibility.

Comment: also answering a question in different format is i think a bit confusing. given that the question is not yet in es6, then it should be answered the same way as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how JS scope works. 
Function which You are passing to *hover*, is executed when hover event occurs. But at the time when it happens, Your *i* variable has value of *icons.length* because Your *for* loop already stopped iterating.

What You need, is to get Your animation function reference, when *hover* event occurs.

Theres sample code written in ES6

```
const animationsSet = [{
  element: '#know',
  animation: knowTl
}, {
  element: '#run',
  animation: runTl
}]

animationsSet.forEach(({ element, animation }) =>
  $(element).hover(() => animation.restart())
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may avoid the closure.

In order to attach the **hover** event to all **icons** elements you can use:

```
$(icons.toString()).hover(
```

In this way you will avoid the for loop at all.

Now the problem: how get the index **i**?

This step can be solved looking for the index:

```
var i = icons.indexOf('#' + this.id);
```

As per comment reported by ***grzesiekgs*** you may add a new attribute to each element.
So, the previous selector can be chained with:

```
.attr('idx', (idx, attr) => {return idx;})
```

And inside the handler you can use directly the new attribute.

And so the snippet:

```js
var icons = ["#know", "#run", "#think", "#done", "#measure", "#plan", "#resolve"];
var animations = ['knowTl', 'runTl', 'thinkTl', 'doneTl', 'measureTL', 'planTl', 'resolveTl'];

$(icons.toString())
           .attr('idx', (idx, attr) => {return idx;})
           .hover(
           function () {
            var i = icons.indexOf('#' + this.id);
            
            var idxAttr = this.getAttribute('idx');

           
            console.log('IN (idxAttr =' + idxAttr + '): animations[' + i + ']=' + animations[i]);
            //animations[i].restart()
        },
        function () {
            // var i = icons.indexOf('#' + this.id);
            // console.log('OUT: animations[' + i + ']=' + animations[i]);
        }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p id="know">know</p>
<p id="run">run</p>
<p id="think">think</p>
<p id="done">done</p>
<p id="measure">measure</p>
<p id="plan">plan</p>
<p id="resolve">resolve</p>
```

Comment: If You want to go this way, it would be way better to just add custom attribute on element, which will hold name of the function, and just hold the functions in one map, and access them by key.

But I don't get whats the point of avoiding ONE closure, when You are using jQuery anyway.

Comment: @grzesiekgs Thanks for sharing. Yes, you are right. Adding an attribute is the best. Why avoid closure? First: the problem I see is how to use selectors in jQuery. The second is: a closure create a new context..... What's your idea?

Comment: Well modern JS compilers can handle creation of new closures quite well. Even with IE11 it's not so painful to create a closure. So IMO theres no point in avoiding it, especially when it makes Your code more readable.

Write code for humans, not for machine. 
*premature optimization is the root of all evil*

Comment: @grzesiekgs Well answer. Thanks again for sharing. It's always a pleasure using this site for sharing ideas, even if  my idea is different. See the updated answer. +1